# Экспедиции на планеты Галактики

Tags: алгоритм

В галактике разворачивается борьба сил Добра и сил Зла.

Известно, что каждая планета Галактики содержит несколько телепортов для перемещения на другие планеты. В давние времена часть телепортов была создана силами Добра, а часть - силами Зла. Прошли века, но как и прежде только силы Добра могут пройти через телепорт Добра, и только силы Зла - через телепорт Зла.

Армии Добра и Зла планируют экспедиции на планеты Галактики. Каждая экспедиция может управлять планетой назначения и всеми другими, непосредственно доступными через телепорты планетами.

Известна квадратная матрица телепортов размерностью ПxП вида

```
 0 +1 -1
+1  0 -1
-1 -1  0
```

где 0 - отсутствие телепортов между планетами, 1 - наличие телепорта Добра, -1 - телепорта Зла.

Выясните могут ли силы Добра одержать победу в Галактике, сколько экспедиций потребуется и в какие планеты их надо направить, если планируется послать Э экспедиций, где Э таково, что число планет П меньше, чем 2 в степени Э.

Comment: Совершенно непонятные условия:

- Что из себя представляет экспедиция? Захват планеты, построка телепорта на ней?
- Что значит "экспедиция может управлять планетой"? 
- Посылать экспедиции можно с любой планеты с телепортом на любую другую? Или только на соседние планеты без телепорта? Или как?
- Что случится, если обе стороны одновременно отправят экспедиции на одну и туже планету?
- Какие условия одержания победы в галактике? Тотальное уничтожение, численное превосходство?
- При чем тут вообще телепорты?

Comment: Условие победы - это доступ ко всем планетам Галактики. То есть если экспедиции находятся в таких планетах, что могут оттуда через один телепорт попасть во все остальные планеты, и количество экспедиций меньше заданного, то победа достигнута. Задача симметрично относительно сил Добра и Зла. С алгоритмической точки зрения, про силы Зла можно забыть и просто расположить экспедиции Добра по ключевым планетам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите, пожалуйста, условие победы добра. Если победа заключается в том, что добро должно иметь доступ в каждую планету галактики, то задачу можно решить неориентированными невзвешенными графами, где вершины это планеты, а связи это телепорты. И тут  можно совершенно пренебречь телепортами зла, потому что нужно найти все "островки" (такие группы планет, где из каждой планеты из этой группы можно попасть в любую другую планету из этой же группы). Причём "островок" может состоять только из одной планеты. Потом нужно посчитать количество таких "островков". Если их больше чем Э, то проигрыш, иначе победа.

Answer (score 3):

Разобьем граф на компоненты связанности, найдем ответ для каждой компоненты. Так как для победы необходимо "*через **один** телепорт попасть во все остальные планеты*", то задача сводится к нахождению вершинного покрытия. [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C7%E0%E4%E0%F7%E0_%EE_%E2%E5%F0%F8%E8%ED%ED%EE%EC_%EF%EE%EA%F0%FB%F2%E8%E8) говорит, что это NP-полная задача. Для её решения можно, например, перебирать вхождение каждой вершины в покрытие за O(2^n) и проверять достижимость каждой вершины за O(n^2). Итого O(2^n * n^2).